# GNU Makefile Questions

Tags: makefile, directory, gnu-make

I'm trying to figure out some differences in makefiles and what some of the code does. Below are some of the different items that I'm trying to address.

- CC vs $(CC)
- CP vs $(CP)
- LD vs $(LD)
- -Wl

This line of code. Is it setting a target of .o files to .c files in the first line? I understand the second line sets flags for compiling, but I don't quite understand the notation at -c $< -o *.o. -c is a flag to generate the object file, $< is the name of the prerequisite(don't really understand this), and -o I'm not certain of.

```
$(libSup)/%.o : %.c
    $(MINGW_CC) $(ADDED_CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_INCLUDE) -c $< -o $(libSup)/$*.o
```

Comment: `-c` and `-o` are compiler flags and don't strictly have anything to do make, the rest of your questions are answered extensively in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).

Comment: `CC` is a variable; `$(CC)` will be expanded to the value of that variable. I can't even parse your first question (*"Is it setting..."*), but I think you ought to start with simpler exercises.